# $2\times2$ confusion matrix for clustering in R

Tags: r, clustering, k-means, confusion-matrix

Given the following:

```
library(rpart.plot)
iris <- read.csv("iris.csv")
my.control <- rpart.control(cp = 0, minsplit=5, xval=10)
iris.rpart <- rpart(Species ~ ., iris[,-6], method='class',
           control=my.control, parms=list(split='gini'))
iris.rpart2 <- prune(iris.rpart, cp=0.094)
table(Original = iris$Species,
      Predicted = predict(iris.rpart2, type='class'))
```

This yields a 3x3 matrix of original and predicted values.

**Question:** *Using this data, how do I now create a 2x2 confusion matrix of true/false labels from the original dataset on one axis, and true/false labels from the algorithm on the other axis?* This would be a sort of aggregate confusion matrix.

Desired Output:

```
                       True labels:
                     disagree agree
Algorithm labels:
            disagree    A       B
            agree       C       D
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. If you have a data.frame `df` with two columns, true membership and predicted membership, you can simply do `table(df)`

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is to look at *pairs* of objects, where a pair exists if and only if both objects are in the *same* cluster.
That way, you can get the usual pre/rec/f1 measures, and also rand, ARI etc. are computed from this matrix.

Comment: +1, but could you provide a simple example to illustrate this? Eg, there are N(N-1)/2 possible pairs, which presumably needs to be accounted for relative to the standard confusion matrix / AUC, etc, for say logistic reg.